# Long running task in a google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have some operations (basically create new folders and links), which can take several minutes. Now the problem is that in this time chrome does somehow block such that i barely can use the browser (in the "check popup-mode"), which is bad. In addition my spinner gif does not spin. ^^

Besides that the operation is aborted if I click on another tab or so (which closes the extension) in the normal mode, which is also bad.

Does anyone have some ideas to handle these cases?

Answer (score 3):

You'll do the long-running tasks in a [background page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html). To notify the background page from the popup when to start the task, you can use [message passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html). Since the background page is always open, it will not stop running when you navigate away from the popup.

Comment: I wasn't quite that background pages solve the problem with the busy loop, but in that case I'll give it a try.

Comment: It seems to work but somehow if i now call chrome.bookmarks.getTree from the background_page.html the function doesn't return. 
I couldn't find any hint that one doesn't have access to the bookmarks from the background.. any ideas why this doesn't work?

Comment: Unless you provide code it will be hard to say what's wrong. Are you sure the background page code is running at all, and that the problem does not lie in the message passing?

Comment: Yes, i tried it and got response right before the call to the bookmarks function.
 
    ...
    (1)
    chrome.bookmarks.getTree(function(nodes)
    {...
    (2) 

(1) is reached but (2) not any more. If I call this code not from the background_page it works as expected.

Comment: as of manifest v3 long running processes are no longer allowed beyond 5min

Comment: Is there a new way to get around the 5 minute limit?